# Odoo 16 (Fresh Install) - Error while trying to create a new contract for any employee

Tags: odoo-16

Today, I have installed a fresh copy of Odoo 16 community version. After setting up basic things in accounting module I have started setting up Employees module. After defining departments and job positions, I have started adding employees.. Then I started adding contract for the employees.. Unfortunately I am getting an error which I searched all over the forums on the internet with no luck.

Every time I try to save the contract, after filling each and every field, I get the following popup. also I have tried to fill the basic required fields in the contract.. I get the same error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\Odoo16\server\odoo\http.py", line 1578, in _serve_db
    return service_model.retrying(self._serve_ir_http, self.env)
  File "C:\Program Files\Odoo16\server\odoo\service\model.py", line 134, in retrying
    result = func()
  File "C:\Program Files\Odoo16\server\odoo\http.py", line 1607, in _serve_ir_http
    response = self.dispatcher.dispatch(rule.endpoint, args)
  File "C:\Program Files\Odoo16\server\odoo\http.py", line 1804, in dispatch
    result = self.request.registry['ir.http']._dispatch(endpoint)
  File "C:\Program Files\Odoo16\server\odoo\addons\website\models\ir_http.py", line 227, in _dispatch
    response = super()._dispatch(endpoint)
  File "C:\Program Files\Odoo16\server\odoo\addons\base\models\ir_http.py", line 140, in _dispatch
    result = endpoint(**request.params)
  File "C:\Program Files\Odoo16\server\odoo\http.py", line 698, in route_wrapper
    result = endpoint(self, *args, **params_ok)
  File "C:\Program Files\Odoo16\server\odoo\addons\web\controllers\dataset.py", line 42, in call_kw
    return self._call_kw(model, method, args, kwargs)
  File "C:\Program Files\Odoo16\server\odoo\addons\web\controllers\dataset.py", line 33, in _call_kw
    return call_kw(request.env[model], method, args, kwargs)
  File "C:\Program Files\Odoo16\server\odoo\api.py", line 459, in call_kw
    result = _call_kw_model_create(method, model, args, kwargs)
  File "C:\Program Files\Odoo16\server\odoo\api.py", line 439, in _call_kw_model_create
    result = method(recs, *args, **kwargs)
  File "<decorator-gen-218>", line 2, in create
  File "C:\Program Files\Odoo16\server\odoo\api.py", line 409, in _model_create_multi
    return create(self, [arg])
  File "C:\Program Files\Odoo16\server\odoo\addons\hr_contract\models\hr_contract.py", line 259, in create
    contracts = super().create(vals_list)
  File "<decorator-gen-142>", line 2, in create
  File "C:\Program Files\Odoo16\server\odoo\api.py", line 410, in _model_create_multi
    return create(self, arg)
  File "C:\Program Files\Odoo16\server\odoo\addons\mail\models\mail_thread.py", line 258, in create
    threads = super(MailThread, self).create(vals_list)
  File "<decorator-gen-65>", line 2, in create
  File "C:\Program Files\Odoo16\server\odoo\api.py", line 410, in _model_create_multi
    return create(self, arg)
  File "C:\Program Files\Odoo16\server\odoo\addons\base\models\ir_fields.py", line 665, in create
    recs = super().create(vals_list)
  File "<decorator-gen-13>", line 2, in create
  File "C:\Program Files\Odoo16\server\odoo\api.py", line 410, in _model_create_multi
    return create(self, arg)
  File "C:\Program Files\Odoo16\server\odoo\models.py", line 3884, in create
    raise ValueError("Invalid field %r on model %r" % (key, self._name))
ValueError: Invalid field 'analytic_precision' on model 'hr.contract'
```

As said before, every time I try to save the contract, after filling each and every field, I get the same error popup

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same error, and it happens because of using `om_hr_payroll_account` custom module.

I have fixed the issue and already created [a pull request](https://github.com/odoomates/odooapps/pull/92) to the author to fix this issue.

You can update the module as per my change in the [pull request files](https://github.com/odoomates/odooapps/pull/92/files).

Answer (score 0):

analytic_precision = fields.Integer(
string="Analytic Precision",
help="Set the precision for analytic accounts")``